Rotation calculation disagreement between Wolfram Alpha and Scipy?
I'm trying to validate quaternion and rotation array conversions using Scipy and WolframAlpha.
Converting quaternions to rotation matrices, I'm using Scipy:
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

quat = np.array([1,2,3,1])
rotmat = quat2rotmat(quat)
solmat = np.array(
    [
        [-1 / 3, 2 / 3, 2 / 3],
        [14 / 15, 1 / 3, 2 / 15],
        [-2 / 15, 2 / 3, -11 / 15]
    ]
)
np.alltrue(rotmat==solmat)

which checks out fine, and rotmat is:
[[-0.33333333  0.66666667  0.66666667]
 [ 0.93333333  0.33333333  0.13333333]
 [-0.13333333  0.66666667 -0.73333333]]

But when I perform the reverse, things don't seem to work as expected. I tried two of the arguments illustrated in the Scipy docs.
rm = np.array(
    [
        [-1 / 3, 2 / 3, 2 / 3],
        [14 / 15, 1 / 3, 2 / 15],
        [-2 / 15, 2 / 3, -11 / 15]
    ]
)
rquat1 = R.from_matrix(rm).as_quat()
rquat2 = R.from_matrix(rm).as_quat(canonical=True)
rquat3 = R.from_matrix(rm).as_quat(scalar_first=True)

which provides:
rquat1 = [0.51639778 0.77459667 0.25819889 0.25819889]
rquat2 = [0.51639778 0.77459667 0.25819889 0.25819889]
rquat3 = [0.25819889 0.51639778 0.77459667 0.25819889]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to bring WolframAlpha and Scipy into compliance.

Divide rquat3 by its first element and you will get the original back. It's just normalised, that's all.
